# Setup for attaching drywall to metal studs

Tags: drywall, studs, powertools, steel

What type of screwdriver setup is best to use for attaching drywall to nonstructural steel studs? Yesterday, I tried using my dedicated drywall screwdriver with fine-threaded drywall screws (which specifically advertised they could be used with light-gauge steel studs) to attach 1/2" drywall. This resulted in the screw stripping a hole in the stud. After about 3 screws of the same result, I switched to an impact driver and screwed in the rest of the screws flush on that same sheet of drywall without any special effort to keep from driving the heads in too far or stripping the hole (no drywall simpler attachment or anything, just a magnetic bit holder).

While I may have gotten lucky with good results on a single drywall sheet using my impact driver since its sensitive enough that I can really slow it down and control it's motion, what setup is typically recommended for attaching drywall to nonstructural steel studs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you used originally is what it used every day by professionals, handymen and DIYers alike. A drywall gun with fine thread drywall screws. For heavier studs drill-point drywall screws can be used.

If what you did works for you then keep at it. It's just a lot slower than a drywall gun. So if this is just for you and small projects there is nothing wrong with an impact and a sensitive hand.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. Looks like I'll just need to do a bit more practicing on some spare studs and drywall to perfect the technique.